# Как сделать цифровые часы формата "00:00" в левой части (лого) Toolbar?

Tags: java, android

Возникла проблема, которую нужно решить. В приложении нужно сделать так, чтобы в левой части toolbar отображадись цифровые часы, которые показывают определенное время с изменением значения. Можно ли такое реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это сделать довольно просто. Берете ваш тулбар, и назначаете ему title. Есть три варианта:
 Если у вас в разметке он есть, то просто находите его по id:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

и дальше пишите такую строку:

```
toolbar.setTitle("ваше время");
```

Второй вариант - если нет тулбара, то вы можете найти тулбар на активити программно и сетить ему надпись:

```
getSupportActionBar()...  //или как-то так)
```

Третий вариант - использовать ваш тулбар как полноценный view элемент с полноценной настройкой:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

и дальше уже находите textView и задаете ему текст какой вам нужен. Удачи :)

Answer (score 3):

Можно, в toolbar, в отличии от action bar, есть возможность вставлять View элементы.

Из книги Android programming guide, big nerd ranch:

Another interesting addition with the toolbar is the ability to place  Views inside of the toolbar and to also adjust the height of the toolbar. This allows for much more flexibility in the way that your app works.

Comment: Да только ActionBar это тоже View , который позволял делать что-то setCustomView. А из перевода не говорится что нельзя , просто позволяет делать это более гибко, скорей всего имеется ввиду xml

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо! Нашел вариант, используя View-элемент TextClock.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/338043)

Comment: Хорошо. Больше так делать не буду